# I want to adjust a background to this leaflet in one section, but the picture has other dimensions, how can i make it fit?

Tags: includegraphics, leaflet

```
\documentclass[10pt, notumble, letterpaper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\title{$7^\circ$ Congreso Internacional sobre Enseñanza de la
Matemática Asistida por Computadora}
\author{Instituto Tecnológico de Costa Rica}
\date{16-18, Noviembre, 2011 }
\CutLine*{1}% linea punteada sin tijeras
\CutLine*{3}% linea punteada sin tijeras
\CutLine*{4}% linea punteada sin tijeras
\CutLine{6}% linea punteada con tijeras

\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames, x11names, table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{LIGHTGRAY}{gray}{.95}

\AddToBackground{3}{% Fondo de la página pequeña 1
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{leaflet.jpg}}}

%\AddToBackground{6}{% Fondo de la página pequeña 6
%\put(0,0){\textcolor{Cyan!50}{\rule{\paperwidth }{\paperheight }}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Sección 1}
Texto en la sección 1



\newpage
\section{Sección 2}
Texto en la sección 2
\newpage
\section{Sección 3}
Texto en la sección 3
\newpage
\section{Sección 4}
Texto en la sección 4
\newpage
\section{Sección 5}
Texto en la sección 5
\newpage
\section{Sección 6}
Texto en la sección 6
\section{Sección 7}
Texto en la sección 7
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does using `width=\pagewidth` instead of `scale=0.5` give the result you want?

Comment: @Thérèse Yes, thanks¡¡ [width=\pagewidth, height=\pageheight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the page with an image without preserving its aspect ratio, replace `scale=0.5` with `width=\pagewidth,height=\pageheight`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notumble,letterpaper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}% this is the default in leaflet, so you don’t need this line
\title{$7^\circ$ Congreso Internacional sobre Enseñanza de la
  Matemática Asistida por Computadora}
\author{Instituto Tecnológico de Costa Rica}
\date{16--18, Noviembre, 2011}% I’ve changed your hyphen to an en-dash
\CutLine*{1}
\CutLine*{3}
\CutLine*{4}
\CutLine{6}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{LIGHTGRAY}{gray}{.95}
\AddToBackground{3}{%
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\pagewidth,height=\pageheight]{example-image-1x1}}}% image supplied by mwe package
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Sección 1}
Texto en la sección 1
\newpage
\section{Sección 2}
Texto en la sección 2
\newpage
\section{Sección 3}
Texto en la sección 3
\newpage
\section{Sección 4}
Texto en la sección 4
\newpage
\section{Sección 5}
Texto en la sección 5
\newpage
\section{Sección 6}
Texto en la sección 6
\section{Sección 7}
Texto en la sección 7
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample]

To tile the page with the image in its original aspect ratio, you can use the `wallpaper` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notumble,letterpaper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{$7^\circ$ Congreso Internacional sobre Enseñanza de la
  Matemática Asistida por Computadora}
\author{Instituto Tecnológico de Costa Rica}
\date{16--18, Noviembre, 2011}
\CutLine*{1}
\CutLine*{3}
\CutLine*{4}
\CutLine{6}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{LIGHTGRAY}{gray}{.95}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Sección 1}
Texto en la sección 1
\newpage
\section{Sección 2}
Texto en la sección 2
\newpage
\ThisTileSquareWallPaper{1}{example-image-1x1}
\section{Sección 3}
Texto en la sección 3
\newpage
\section{Sección 4}
Texto en la sección 4
\newpage
\section{Sección 5}
Texto en la sección 5
\newpage
\section{Sección 6}
Texto en la sección 6
\section{Sección 7}
Texto en la sección 7
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second sample]

Comment: Thanks Thérese, and to reduce the opacity of this background image? I am trying \transparent{0.7} and set it on different parts of the code but it doesn't work....

Comment: That would be another question, which you should feel free to open if you can’t find a solution that works with leaflet. My first instinct would be to use the `background` package, and you’ll find examples of its usage on this site.